# Windows 11 warns against installing xampp

Tags: xampp

I have a relatively new PC on Windows 11, 22 h2, the latest. I have been down multiple paths trying to get localhost to open on this PC. I searched to see if my edition blocks it, but have found no such problem documented.

Following this frustration, and as a throwing up my hands experience, I said fine, I will install Xampp if it's going to act like that.

Immediate upon clicking the exe file (xampp-windows-x64-8.1.10-0-VS16-installer.exe), windows throws a warning, and gives two choice, Run anyway or Don't run. The blue background screen has these words:

Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.

I never saw this in Windows 10 with my old PC. Why now?

App:
xampp-windows-x64-8.1.10-0-VS16-installer.exe
Publisher:
ES, Sevilla, Open Source Developer, "Open Source Developer, Beltran Rueda", beltran@apachefriends.org

Comment: I asked the same question here, but apparently nobody understood it. I have worked with XAMPP in the past. It works very well on Windows 10. When I switched to Windows 11, I spent like 18 hours trying to fix it just to install Wordpress. When I did fix the phpMyAdmin problem, it still didn't fix the Wordpress problem. 

I guess it is that XAMPP staff has to make some updates for Windows 11.